# Finding simple bifurcation point

Tags: nonlinear-system, chaos-theory

$\dot{x}=x-rx\left ( 1-x \right )$

I know where the fixed point occurs but what about the bifurcation points. I thought I knew how to find the bifurcation points. At least, for simple ODE where I can sketch via hand. But beyond that, what is the technique to finding the bifurcation points $r_{c}$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: **Hint:** Factor as $r x^2 − (r − 1)x  = 0$ (find the roots of the quadratic). Can you proceed now? What value(s) of $r$ give you $x' = 0$ from the previous hint?

Comment: The root is r=-x/(x-1). No, I can't. I'm not getting the big picture as to how the bifurcation point fits in with solving for the root. My notes mention that the bifurcation point is the point where the vector field changes. Evidently, with a picture, this is obvious as to where the vector field changes.@Moo

Comment: No. $x^* = 0, \dfrac{r-1}{r}$. What value of $r$ makes this expression zero? This gives you the two critical points. Proceed.

Comment: I have 2 fixed points as you have worked out. r=1 makes the second fixed point $x^{\ast}=0$@Moo

Comment: Yes I can proceed to finding stability(in principle, unless things gets overly complicated that geometric intepretation to solutions to ODE is required).
What I wanted was the value $r_{c}$ and I think you pointed me in the direction. Basically, to find $r_{c}$, find the fixed points and find the values of r for which $x^{\ast}=0$, is this true?@Moo

Comment: As an aside, is $r_{c}$ even called the bifurcation value(s)? Or is it a parameter control for the ode?@Moo

Comment: $r$ is the bifurcation parameter now. If $r$ is fixed, then the question reduces to a simple phase-diagram problem; but since $r$ is a parameter (which can be any real number), you want to find $r$ such that the stability of fixed point(s) changes. Note that your fixed point should depends on $r$ too.

Comment: Indeed, one of my fixed points is a function of r.@CheeHan

Comment: Nice. The next step will be to draw separate phase diagrams to determine the stability of your fixed point (for different values of $r$).

Comment: @CheeHan Correct.

Comment: You should find that there is only one critical value of $r$, say, $r_c$, where the two fixed points exchange stability. This is sometimes called a transcritical bifurcation.

Comment: Yes @Moo. I drew the phase diagram.